# Codeigniter : array to string conversion error

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my model:

```
public function count_diabetic(){
    $query = $this->db->query("Select count(diabetic) as count_diabetic from member where diabetic is not NULL");

    return $query->result_array();
} 

public function count_hypertensive(){
    $query = $this->db->query("Select count(hypertensive) as count_hypertensive from member where hypertensive is not NULL");

    return $query->result();
}
```

here is my controller:

```
public function home(){
             $this->load->model('Jsv_model');
             $data = array(

                'count_diabetic' => $this->Jsv_model->count_diabetic(),
                'count_hypertensive' => $this->Jsv_model->count_hypertensive()

             ); 

             $this->session->set_userdata($data);   

            $this->load->view('home');
    }
```

Here is my view with in php tag:

```
 echo $this->session->userdata('count_diabetic');
```

But Here it shows error that array to string conversion error..
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `count_diabetic()` you should change `$query->result_array()`

**into**

`$query->row()->count_diabetic`,

it would return number of count only not array.

Do it to `count_hypertensive()` too.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can display arrays by using the `print_r` function instead of `echo`.

For example, you have to change your code to:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata['count_diabetic']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong in this line.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('count_diabetic');
```

What should you do?

```
// To Set a Data in Session
$session_data = array(
    'count_diabetic' => $this->Jsv_model->count_diabetic(),
    'count_hypertensive' => $this->Jsv_model->count_hypertensive()  
    );      
$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $session_data); 

// To get the session data
 $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
 $user_name = $session_data['username'];
 $count_diabetic = $session_data['count_diabetic'];
 $count_hypertensive = $session_data['count_hypertensive'];
```